# Xdebug with PhpStorm on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, phpstorm, xdebug

I am wondering if anyone can shed any light on the appropriate measures to take to ensure that the following set up will allow Xdebug and PhpStorm to work.

We have a LAMP stack running fine, with PHP and Xdebug 3 running on an Azure VM.

We are on a shared office network with a public IP address but no access to the firewall for the incoming line, although it's very relaxed.

We are aiming to connect our machines (x3) to debug our remote web server (the LAMP stack on the Azure VM).

We can create the SSH tunnel no problem to the web server. But debugging just doesn't work. I.e. when we fire up a page, the debugger does nothing at all.

Is anyone else running this kind of set up and confirm whether we are missing a step to ensure a successful connection.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.force_display_errors = 1
xdebug.scream = 1
xdebug.force_error_reporting = NONE
xdebug.idekey = diss
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
```

Comment: 1) Yes, SSH is needed since you cannot open ports on firewall/router. 2) If you going to have multiple devs working at the same time ... you better look at DBGp Proxy (in combination with SSH tunnel I guess). 3) Do not mix Xdebug v2 and v3 config params. v3 will **complain** in your error log every time it sees v2 param (you do not need such useless flood).

Comment: 4) Try `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` -- this tells Xdebug to try and debug **every single script/request** without looking for "debug me" flag (cookie or ENV/GET/POST param) -- keep it until you make it work, then you can remove it to have a better control. 5) Post your Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output + `xdebug_info()` captured in a same way as you are trying to debug it (CLI script or a web page -- important as your OS may use different php.ini for different env)

Comment: 6) Check the Xdebug log -- it will tell where it tries to connect to and what the response is. If log is empty: A) wrong path (Ubuntu virtualizes if `/tmp/` is used); B) file permissions C) Xdebug is not trying to debug anything D) Something prevents that (e.g. SELinux or alike) -- rather unlikely to happen in containers, but may still affect Apache. 7) Check with `telnet` if your SSH tunnel is set up correctly (connect from within your VM/container back to the IDE -- PhpStorm mu be listening for connections at that stage (green phone handle icon) -- able to connect?

Comment: P.S. If you are debugging a **CLI script**, then you should be able to debug from many simultaneous sessions (just use different Xdebug port in IDE, IDE will pass these params when initiating CLI debug from IDE (you must have Remote PHP Interpreter configured for that). For **web page debug** though you cannot pass that (as it's all run on server with no control from your end) so something like DBGp Proxy has to be used to have multiple devs (as it's made for that): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/multiuser-debugging-via-xdebug-proxies.html

Comment: @LazyOne DBGp Proxy - I am looking at this now. Can I run it permanently in the background on the development server?

Comment: I have not used it myself (had no need for such setup). But looking at how it works, yes, the proxy software needs to run there on your server in bg. Also: https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgpProxy

Comment: P.S. At some point Xdebug 3 will support Xdebug Cloud, so it will be much easier to set up stuff like this. PhpStorm will support it as well. 1) https://cloud.xdebug.com/ 2) https://vimeo.com/444254115

Comment: I seem to have multiple users now connecting through the proxy, but when one of them loads a page the debugger opens on my PC

Comment: 1) Did you made IDE Key to be unique for EACH developer (in PhpStorm's DBGp Proxy settings)? Proxy decides what developer to contact based on the IDE key used. 2) Obviously, when using Xdebug browser extension (or passing that via GET/POST param instead of COOKIE way that extension uses), it also should have the same unique IDE key. **P.S.**  you can also use bookmarklets instead of browser extension for that: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt reply. Yeah each dev has their own unique IDE key and then our Debug Helpers are set up to use our respective IDE keys.

Comment: I've made a post here with more info in, can you see if you can see anything obvious please? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010264920-xdebug-multiple-developers-php-storm-dbgpproxy

Comment: Sadly nothing from my end (as I have never used DBGp Proxy myself -- never had a need for that). From what I see JetBrains person have already posted some suggestion there -- hopefully it will make it work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved in my case by ensuring the settings were as follows

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

I use pydbgpproxy

```
    cd /opt
    sudo mkdir pydbgpproxy
    cd pydbgpproxy
    sudo wget https://github.com/Mirocow/pydbgpproxy/archive/master.zip ./
    sudo unzip master.zip ./
    sudo ln -s $(pwd)/pydbgpproxy /usr/local/bin/pydbgpproxy
```

Edit the pydbgpproxy

```
cd /opt/pydbgpproxy/pydbgpproxy-master/
sudo nano pydbgpproxy
```

In line 333 replace line add=xxx with

```
addr = ['127.0.0.1',long(idekey)]
```

Start pydbgproxy on the server

```
nohup sudo /opt/pydbgpproxy/pydbgpproxy-master/pydbgpproxy -i 127.0.0.1:1001-d 127.0.0.1:1003 &
```

Create an SSH connection to the development server with an SSH tunnel:

```
Source Port: 1234 **This must match your unique IDE key set below.**
Destination: 127.0.0.1:1003
```

Change your debugger port to 9003 in PhpStorm
`File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug`

```
Debug Port: 1003
```

Change your proxy settings to:
`File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug > DBGp Proxy`

```
IDE Key: 1234 **Unique IDE Key - This must be unique to you and must be numerical**
Host: 0.0.0.0 **External IP Address of the Dev Server**
Port: 1001
```

Make sure your xdebug helper extension is set to use key 1234

**What you set as your IDE key above, must be unique**